# Two files - need to find individuals unique to file A - perl or python or awk etc

Tags: regex, matching

I have two files, A and B. I need to output only those individuals **not** in file B, the unique lines in file A.

File A looks like:

```
SNP CHR GeneticDistance BP P
rs1043096 1 0.000000 111682307 1.6478397881920986E-06
rs6661407 1 0.000000 230654589 6.5655676421792970E-06
rs1822312 1 0.000000 146687250 6.9190273469706007E-06
rs7533254 1 0.000000 34181830 1.8066585187932294E-05
rs1414355 1 0.000000 89828716 2.0823984140492505E-05
rs237425 1 0.000000 94012287 4.3816651855534701E-05
```

File B looks like:

```
rs1043096
rs1822312
```

And the output would like:

```
SNP CHR GeneticDistance BP P
rs6661407 1 0.000000 230654589 6.5655676421792970E-06
rs7533254 1 0.000000 34181830 1.8066585187932294E-05
rs1414355 1 0.000000 89828716 2.0823984140492505E-05
rs237425 1 0.000000 94012287 4.3816651855534701E-05
```

I don't even know where to begin, and I don't know what language to use! I presumably can't use a !=in regexp or I'll get everything else in the file that doesn't match line by line, rather than just the lines unique to file A

Can I modify something like this? sort fileA fileB | uniq -u > fileC

Or this? I'm finding it tricky because the lines in file A and B don't look identical anyway.

```
open(FILE1, "< fileA.txt");
open(FILE2, "< fileB.txt");

@file1 = <FILE1>;
@file2 = <FILE2>;

foreach $line (@file1, @file2)
{
    chomp($line);
    $TEXT{$line}++;
}

foreach $line (sort keys %TEXT)
{
    if ($TEXT{$line} == 1)
    {
         print $line . "\n";
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use `awk`, this can work:

```
$ awk 'NR == FNR{a[$0];next} !($1 in a)' fileB fileA
SNP CHR GeneticDistance BP P
rs6661407 1 0.000000 230654589 6.5655676421792970E-06
rs7533254 1 0.000000 34181830 1.8066585187932294E-05
rs1414355 1 0.000000 89828716 2.0823984140492505E-05
rs237425 1 0.000000 94012287 4.3816651855534701E-05
```

The code is explained in [Idiomatic awk](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/).

Basically it loops through the fileB and gets those lines in fileA whose first field (`$1`) is not in fileB.

Do not hesitate to ask if you need further explanation. However, I think in the web is quite well explained and I could not improve it :)

Comment: Oh that's elegant. How could I modify if get the results printed as tab delimited, please?

Comment: For this, you can use `OFS='\t'`: `awk -v OFS="\t" 'NR == FNR{a[$0];next} !($1 in a) {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' fileB fileA
`

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -Fv -f B A
 # or
fgrep -v -f B A
```

This will list each line in A which does not match any of the strings in B.

You may have a problem with short values in `B` matching the prefix of values in `A` in which case you could add a space to each line in `B`:

```
sed 's/$/ /' B | fgrep -v -f - A
```